# Java data structures

Tags: java, data-structures, tree

I am not an experienced programmer but I am trying to finish an assignment and seem to be stuck.

Basically we are told to write an inorder traversal of the tree to an array and then use a recursive method (much like binary search) to insert the middle element of the array as the root, and then build balanced left and right subtrees.

I keep getting an error that the list seems to be empty?

Code:

```
{

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        LinkedBinarySearchTree<Integer> hello = new LinkedBinarySearchTree<>(3);

        hello.addElement(20);
        hello.addElement(9);
        hello.addElement(112);
        hello.addElement(1);
        hello.addElement(20);

        System.out.println(hello.toString());

        ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();

        //copy the tree elements into an arraylist
        Iterator<Integer> itr = hello.iteratorInOrder();

        while (itr.hasNext()){
            list.add(itr.next());

        }

        //print to check if the elements are copied

        System.out.println(list.toString());    

        //create a new tree and set the root as the balanced tree node
        LinkedBinarySearchTree<Integer> balanced = new LinkedBinarySearchTree<>();

        balanced.SetRoot(buildBalancedTree(list));

        System.out.println(balanced.toString());


    }

    public static BinaryTreeNode<Integer> buildBalancedTree(List<Integer> list) {

        if (list.isEmpty()) {

            BinaryTreeNode nullNode = new BinaryTreeNode(0);

            return nullNode;

        } else {
            int middle = list.size() / 2;

            BinaryTreeNode<Integer> balanceTree = new BinaryTreeNode<>(list.get(middle));

            //recursive calls
            balanceTree.setLeft(buildBalancedTree(list.subList(0, middle)));
            balanceTree.setRight(buildBalancedTree(list.subList(middle + 1, list.size())));
            return balanceTree;
        }



    }

}
```

output:

1
3
9
20
20
112

[1, 3, 9, 20, 20, 112]
0
1
0
3
0
9
0
20
0
20
0
112
0

Why are the 0s there? And is the tree being constructed properly?

Comment: Did you try debugging?

Comment: instead of using iterator you can copy `AL` as

`ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>(hello);`

Answer (score 0):

You need to stop the recursion when the list is empty. I'd add a corresponding check in the first line of buildBalancedTree.

Comment: Thank you, I edited my code a bit, do you think it is balancing the tree correctly now?

Comment: Can't you just return null?

Answer (score 0):

There is no base case condition written in the code.